# Finding an integer from a string

Tags: javascript

I know you can turn a string into an integer using `Number` and `parseInt`, but I want to get a number from in the middle or at the end of a string. For example:

```
'Number 87' --> 87
'data-2384729' --> 2384729
'Beep 8009 Bop' --> 8009
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RegExp` together with `String#match`.

```js
function getNum(str){
  var res = Number(str.match(/\d+/)[0]);
  console.log(res);
}

getNum('Number 87');
getNum('data-2384729');
getNum('Beep 8009 Bop');
```

Comment: Note .match() returns an array of strings